# dimension of space of origin-symmetric ellipsoids

Tags: convex-analysis, lie-groups, euclidean-geometry

I wonder how I can compute the dimension of the space of all origin-symmetric ellipsoids? What is the best approach?

Comment: We have three parameters as axis and other three for a possible rotation around the origin, so the dimension seems $6$.

Comment: In higher dimensions it should be n(n+1)/2,  right?

Comment: Yes, it seems correct. But for a good answer we need a parametrization of the space... I'm thinking about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the ellipsoid with center at the origin and axis parallel to the coordinate axis, are symmetric with respect the origin and, in $n$ dimensional space, are represented by a quadratic form  $\vec x^T A \vec x=1$ where $A$ is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal elements positive (the reciprocals of the squares of the semi-axes).

Any rotation $R$ in $SO(n)$  transform an ellipsoid of this kind to another ellipsoid symmetric with respect the origin, represented by the equation
$$
\vec x^T (RAR^{-1}) \vec x=1
$$

Now, the space of the diagonal matrices $A$ has dimension $n$, The dimension of $SO(n)$ is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, so the dimension of the space of origin-symmetric ellipsoid is $d=n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.